# AS3 selecting a Combo Box inside a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, movieclip, dataprovider

I am not sure if there is a better way to do this, and if there is please let me know. But right now, I have a list of combo boxes with names in them.

The combo boxes are stu1, stu2, stu3, ect all the way to 63 and held in the allStudents MovieClip

```
for(var i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++)
{
    var newTempStudent:ComboBox = allStudents.getChildAt(i);

    newTempStudent.dataProvider.addItem({label: fullName, data:fullName});
    newTempStudent.getChildAt(i).dataProvider.sortOn("label");
    newTempStudent.getChildAt(i).selectedItem = allStudents.getChildAt(i).getItemAt(i);

}
```

essentially i am trying to:

get all 63 combo boxes to update from the same dataProvider,

sort them alphabetically,

then set the default selected to each student (stu1 should display dataProvider(0), stu2 should display dataProvider(1) as it's default selection)

The error I am getting is:

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 83  1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type fl.controls:ComboBox.

Now I am assuming I am getting that becasue it is looking is the movie clip which is the display object and executing combobox commands, but I'm not sure how to do this per se.

Originally I was going to do this with a dataGrid, but it became too complicated when I was trying to link the dataGrid to checkBoxes for attendance.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++)
{
    var newTempStudent:ComboBox = allStudents.getChildAt(i) as ComboBox;

    newTempStudent.dataProvider.addItem({label: fullName, data:fullName});
    newTempStudent.getChildAt(i).dataProvider.sortOn("label");
    newTempStudent.getChildAt(i).selectedItem = allStudents.getChildAt(i).getItemAt(i) as ComboBox;

}
```

getChildAt() returns a DisplayObject, so you need to cast it as a ComboBox.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to fix the problem :(

Comment: Well, let me clerify...It fixes it sort of... I am getting a new error now : Access of possibly undefined property dataProvider through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject, Call to a possibly undefined method getItemAt through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject, Access of possibly undefined property selectedItem through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Comment: This is not an ongoing thread on all bugs/issues in your program. You had an  implicit coercion error, and I told you how to fix it. If the error is gone, that is answering the question. If you have another error or problem, post another question.

Comment: The goal of stack overflow is to have a concise question/answer format. If it becomes one long thread handling all the issue you have in your program, it's helping you, but becomes less useful to others. It's best to have one question, not multiple that string out into comments.